# sed to get string between two patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I am working on a latex file from which I need to pick out the references marked by \citep{}. This is what I am doing using sed.

```
    cat file.tex | grep citep | sed 's/.*citep{\(.*\)}.*/\1/g'
```

Now this one works if there is only one pattern in a line. If there are more than one patterns i.e. \citep in a line, it fails. It fails even when there is only one pattern but more than one closing bracket }. What should I do, so that it works for all the patterns in a line and also for the exclusive bracket I am looking for?

I am working on bash. And a part of the file looks like this:

```
of the Asian crust further north \citep{TapponnierM76, WangLiu2009}. This has led to widespread deformation both within and 
\citep{BilhamE01, Mitraetal2005} and by distributed seismicity across the region (Fig. \ref{fig1_2}). Recent GPS Geodetic 
across the Dawki fault and Naga Hills, increasing eastwards from $\sim$3~mm/yr to $\sim$13~mm/yr \citep{Vernantetal2014}. 
GPS velocity vectors \citep{TapponnierM76, WangLiu2009}. Sikkim Himalaya lies at the transition between this relatively simple 
this transition includes deviation of the Himalaya from a perfect arc beyond 89\deg\ longitude \citep{BendickB2001}, reduction 
\citep{BhattacharyaM2009, Mitraetal2010}. Rivers Tista, Rangit and Rangli run through Sikkim eroding the MCT and Ramgarh 
thrust to form a mushroom-shaped physiography \citep{Mukuletal2009,Mitraetal2010}. Within this sinuous physiography, 
\citep{Pauletal2015} and also in accordance with the findings of \citet{Mitraetal2005} for northeast India. In another study 
field results corroborate well with seismic studies in this region \citep{Actonetal2011, Arunetal2010}. From studies of
```

On one line, I get answer like this

```
    BilhamE01, TapponnierM76} and by distributed seismicity across the region (Fig. \ref{fig1_2
```

whereas I am looking for

```
    BilhamE01, TapponnierM76
```

Another example with more than one /citep patterns gives output like this

```
    Pauletal2015} and also in accordance with the findings of \citet{Mitraetal2005} for northeast India. In another study
```

whereas I am looking for

```
    Pauletal2015 Mitraetal2005
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: ([Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: @Ed Morton, I have now added that example too.

Comment: Yes, I have understood @Ed Morton. Next time onwards, I will post a file and its output. The problem is solved through Lev' suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `grep` anyway, you can as well stick with it (assuming `GNU grep`):

```
$ echo $str | grep -oP '(?<=\\citep{)[^}]+(?=})'
BilhamE01, TapponierM76
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Lev Levitsky, it solved all of my problems.

Answer (score 3):

it's a greedy match change the regex match the first closing brace

```
.*citep{\([^}]*\)}
```

test

```
$ echo "\citep{string} xyz {abc}" |  sed 's/.*citep{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/'
string
```

note that it will only match one instance per line.

Comment: That won't help his case where `citep` appears multiple times on one line.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Probably I am not clear in my question. From "\citep{string} xyz {abc}", I need to get "string".

Comment: @HimangshuPaul, as karafka demonstrated with his example, his approach will indeed select "string" from the example input you presented.  If that is insufficient then I think you do, still, need to clarify.

Comment: Thanks @karafka. This does works. Earlier I was misled by the }. But, I need a little help on the other portion where /citep appears more than once. I have added an example for that one too now in the question.

Comment: for multiple instances `grep` will be a better choice than `sed`.

Comment: Thanks @John Bollinger for the clarification. This part is solved. For the second part of the problem where multiple /citep appears, I have added an example to my question.

Comment: @karafka, how do I grep all the instances in a line?

Comment: check @Lev Levitsky's answer for the `grep` solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this *can* be done with `sed`:

```
echo "\citep{string} xyz {abc} \citep{string2},foo" | \
  sed 's/\\citep{\([^}]*\)}/\n\1\n\n/g; s/^[^\n]*\n//; s/\n\n[^\n]*\n/, /g; s/\n.*//g'
```

output:

```
string, string2
```

But wow, is that ugly.  The `sed` script is more easily understood in this form, which happens to be suitable to be fed to `sed` via a `-f` argument:

```
# change every \citep{string} to <newline>string<newline><newline>
s/\\citep{\([^}]*\)}/\n\1\n\n/g

# remove any leading text before the first wanted string
s/^[^\n]*\n//

# replace text between wanted strings with comma + space
s/\n\n[^\n]*\n/, /g

# remove any trailing unwanted text
s/\n.*//
```

This makes use of the fact that `sed` can match and sub the newline character, even though reading a new line of input will not result in a newline initially appearing in the pattern space.  The newline is the one character that we can be *certain* will appear in the pattern space (or in the hold space) only if `sed` puts it there intentionally.

The initial substitution is purely to make the problem manageable by simplifying the target delimiters.  In principle, the remaining steps could be performed without that simplification, but the regular expressions involved would be horrendous.

This does assume that the `string` in every `\citep{string}` contains at least one character; if the empty string must be accommodated, too, then this approach needs a bit more refinement.

Of course, I can't imagine why anyone would prefer this to @Lev's straight `grep` approach, but the question does ask specifically for a `sed` solution.

Comment: having an option is always better than having none. That is why I appreciate your effort. As suggested by you, I have edited my answer. Hope it help others. Although, I tried to attach a file, I could not find it and I am not at all satisfied the way I have done. Please suggest if there is a better way to represent a file.

Comment: @HimangshuPaul, you could use a code block or put the file lines in a `<pre>` element to prevent the lines being joined together.

Answer (score 0):

**f.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    pat = "\\citep"
    latex_tok = "\\\\[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_]*" # match \aBcD
}

{
    f = f $0 # store content of input file as a sting
}

function store(args,   n, k, i) { # store `keys' in `d'
    gsub("[ \t]", "", args) # remove spaces
    n = split(args, keys, ",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      k = keys[i]
      d[k]
    }
}

function ntok() { # next token
    if (match(f, latex_tok)) {
      tok = substr(f, RSTART          ,RLENGTH)
      f   = substr(f, RSTART+RLENGTH-1        )
      return 1
    }
    return 0
}

function parse(    i, rc, args) {
    for (;;) { # infinite loop
      while ( (rc = ntok()) && tok != pat ) ;
      if (!rc) return

      i = index(f, "{")
      if (!i) return # see `pat' but no '{'
      f = substr(f, i+1)

      i = index(f, "}")
      if (!i) return # unmatched '}'

      # extract `args' from \citep{`args'}
      args = substr(f, 1, i-1)
      store(args)
    }
}

END {
    parse()
    for (k in d)
      print k
}
```

**f.example**

```
of the Asian crust further north \citep{TapponnierM76, WangLiu2009}. This has led to widespread deformation both within and 
\citep{BilhamE01, Mitraetal2005} and by distributed seismicity across the region (Fig. \ref{fig1_2}). Recent GPS Geodetic 
across the Dawki fault and Naga Hills, increasing eastwards from $\sim$3~mm/yr to $\sim$13~mm/yr \citep{Vernantetal2014}. 
GPS velocity vectors \citep{TapponnierM76, WangLiu2009}. Sikkim Himalaya lies at the transition between this relatively simple 
this transition includes deviation of the Himalaya from a perfect arc beyond 89\deg\ longitude \citep{BendickB2001}, reduction 
\citep{BhattacharyaM2009, Mitraetal2010}. Rivers Tista, Rangit and Rangli run through Sikkim eroding the MCT and Ramgarh 
thrust to form a mushroom-shaped physiography \citep{Mukuletal2009,Mitraetal2010}. Within this sinuous physiography, 
\citep{Pauletal2015} and also in accordance with the findings of \citet{Mitraetal2005} for northeast India. In another study 
field results corroborate well with seismic studies in this region \citep{Actonetal2011, Arunetal2010}. From studies of
```

Usage:

```
awk -f f.awk f.example
```

Expected ouput:

```
BendickB2001
Arunetal2010
Pauletal2015
Mitraetal2005
BilhamE01
Mukuletal2009
TapponnierM76
WangLiu2009
BhattacharyaM2009
Mitraetal2010
Actonetal2011
Vernantetal2014
```